# python pip not working on requirements.txt after OS X 10.8 macports install

Tags: python, macos, pip, macports, requirements.txt

Recently bought a new Mac and was setting it up for both Python and iOS development. Python was working fine--especially pip'ing git repos with lots of requirements.txt dependencies UNTIL I installed Xcode, macports and Apple's command line tools.

Now pip works fine for individual install (e.g., pip install twilio), but whenever I run pip against a requirements.txt file it fails (with or without sudo):

```
pip install ./requirements.txt
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 225, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 118, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 43, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2510, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2436, in parse_requirements
line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2404, in scan_list
raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', './requirements.txt', 'at', '/requirements.txt')
```

My `$PATH` value is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

This looks different than the "Python pip broken after OS X 10.8 upgrade" thread. I am wonder if macports created a conflict between looking in `/System/Libary` and `~/Library`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to install packages through a requirements file, you need the `--requirement/-r` option:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).